# MySQL Grouping results

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv, left-join

My tables

```
Table function
id function users
-----------------
1  f1       1,2
2  f2       2,3
3  f1       4,5
4  f2

Table users
id name
-------
1  Mark
2  Louis
3  John
4  Denver
5  Nat
```

I need to write a query that produces the following results:

```
 f1, Mark, Louis
 f2, Louis, John
 f1, Denver, Nat
 f2
```

Thanks for any help and excuse my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using `find_in_set()` and `group_concat()`:

```
select f.function, group_concat(u.name order by find_in_set(u.id, f.users)) user_names
from `function` f
left join users u on find_in_set(u.id, f.users)
group by f.id
```

Notes:

- `function` is  a language keyword, hence not a good choice for an identifier (column or table name)
- although what you ask for is possible here, storing CSV data in a table is bad practice and should almost always be avoided - see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716)

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0197a8ffd67c39705f5e82ec4fd087e7)**:

```
function | user_names
:------- | :---------
f1       | Mark,Louis
f2       | Louis,John
f1       | Denver,Nat
f2       | null
```

Comment: Once again you help me a lot . Thank you very much GMB for you help and explanation!!!